# Issue with showing call duration after call call terminate

Tags: android, android-activity

I can able to show ongoing call duration in my `CallScreen`. After call terminate I want to show total call duration in toast for that I am writing code `onStop`, but because of call termination Activity get ended and it is not showing call duration. So I want to know what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration);
toast.show();

context is usually user ApplicationContext or Activity use.

Have you been tested getApplicationContext() ApplicationContext use?

I'm test Activity or ApplicationContext, both i'm show toast message.

How to call termination Activity?

Comment: to terminate activity say `finish()`